# Como validar data de nascimento entre o ano de 1900 e Hoje?

Tags: php

Como validar data de nascimento com 3 campos?

Tenho o campo "data1" com o dia, "data2" com o mês e "data3" com o ano, preciso validar a data de nascimento. Esses 3 campos vem de um *bd*.

Seria algo assim:

```
if (validaDataDeNascimento($data1/$data2/$data3))
{
   echo "Data de nascimento inválida.";
}
```

Comment: de 1900 a data atual

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "puxando do bd"? Você tem dados inválidos no banco e quer validar por php? Ou quer validar antes de chegar no banco?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Chamei suas variáveis de `$dia`, `$mes` e `$ano` para facilitar a leitura.

Se quiser saber se a data é válida, basta usar o `checkdate`:

```
checkdate( $mes, $dia, $ano ) // Atenção à ordem dos parâmetros.
```

Para ver se a data é hoje ou anterior:

```
if ( mktime( 0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano ) < time() ) // não precisa de <= (a hora é 0, 0, 0)
```

Para ver se o ano é maior ou igual que 1900:

```
if ( $ano >= 1900 )
```

Juntando tudo, e invertendo as verificações:

```
if ( !checkdate( $mes , $dia , $ano )                   // se a data for inválida
     || $ano < 1900                                     // ou o ano menor que 1900
     || mktime( 0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano ) > time() )  // ou a data passar de hoje
{
   echo 'Data inválida';
}
```

### Caso faça diferença a "virada" da data à meia-noite:

As funções utilizadas acima tomam por base a hora do servidor. Se precisar de mais precisão, uma alternativa é usar a classe `DateTime`, que aceita comparações à partir do *PHP* 5.2.2, e além de `date_default_timezone_set`, o timezone pode ser setado individualmente em cada um dos `DateTime`s, de forma a não interferir com outras partes do script.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$hoje = new DateTime('NOW');
$nascimento = new DateTime();
$nascimento->setDate( $ano, $mes, $dia ); // Novamente, atenção à ordem dos parâmetros.

if ( $nascimento > $hoje ) || ... etc ...
```

Comment: obrigado!!!!!!!!!!!!!!